# Is there any easy way to downgrade an wp OS 8 app to OS 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, downgrade

I've created an app for windows phone OS 8 but I'm wanting to support OS 7.1 as well, is there any easy way I'm able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new project for windows phone 7.1 and then import all your files of the application to that project. Make sure you do not import the *WMAppManifest.xml* file. That file needs to be the actual one from 7.1 project.

Now compile the project. If you any making use of any SDK calls that aren't in 7.1 then you will need to address them! That should not be tough i suppose. There are workarounds for most of them. You can post those errors here for more help.