# How to change target in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, target

Hello i want to make an app for Windows Phone, but on Windows Phone 8.1 it's not possible to deal with SQLite (it's too difficult, cannot event download sqlite-net-wp8 for WP 8.1) How to change my project target to Store App Windows Phone 8.0 or Store App Windows Phone 8.0 SilverLight? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can downgrade any app where as you can only upgrade.

[How to downgrade a Windows Phone 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596973/)

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx) for upgrading an app.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. You can use Visual Studio 2012, or download some sample app wor WP 8.0 and open it in visual studio 2013, delete content, and start coding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the SQLite c++ project you add to your solution correct?
And it seems impossible to get to work on 8.1?

Check this out here. 
[SQLite Windows Phone](http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/04/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-1/)