# Windows Phone app in C#: No option to change target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, target-framework

I have no option to change the target framework of my project. I use VS2013 to develop a C# Windows Phone 8.1 App. All I see is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjcA.png)

Comment: Do you have more Windows Phone SDKs aside the 8.1 SDK?

Comment: @frikinside I think so. Installed products list `Windows Phone SDK 8.0  - ENU` and `Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration`.

Comment: Could yo try to create a new project but select Blank App (Silverlight) project template. I think that should allow you to select target 8.0 OS.

Comment: @frikinside Nope, only `Windows Phone 8.1` is listed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What are you trying to change to framework to?

Comment: @Aniruth sad to hear that! That was my last bullet :/

Comment: @frikinside thanks mate.

Comment: @IgorKulman I want to change the framework because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553136/system-drawing-namespace-not-found-under-console-application) problem. I want to use System.Drawing namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this thread helpful?

[How to change target in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767928/how-to-change-target-in-visual-studio-2013)

It seems like you cannot downgrade to 8.0.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.