# Visual Studio 2012 Windows Phone Application - Target

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

How can I downgrade the target of my project from 8.0 to 7.1?

I tries to set it from project>settings>"Target Windows Phone OS Version" , but in dropdown list there is only one line: "Windows Phone OS 8.0".

Thank you.

Comment: in my opinion, it can't downgrade once change from 7.1 to 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably **not possible**. One thing you can try, set up windows phone 7.0 sdk and try to port your app there from scratch.Yes, i think that's the only way, so create a new project under wp 7.0 and **import all of your files** there.
**SO** also tells about it, some suggestions for you that may help:

- [How to downgrade a Windows Phone 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596973/how-to-downgrade-a-windows-phone-8-app)
- [Is there any easy way to downgrade an wp OS 8 app to OS 7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577146/is-there-any-easy-way-to-downgrade-an-wp-os-8-app-to-os-7-1)